# Can I customize RequestTelemetry properties once at AppStart in Asp.net Web.API

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I want to add a property say version information to RequestTelemetry of (HttpRequest). This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling) provides an approach - by overriding ITelemetryInitializer Initialize method. However, it is getting executed every time when a request hits the server. I want to set it once at App Start as my property( eg., assembly ver/Proj version) does not change often.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this, as you will be getting a new instance of RequestTelemetry with each request.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. TelemetryInitializer override, is a way to collect telemetry in a custom fashion and is called with every request.

Answer (score 0):

I got to know of a way to do this through context initializers but it is not recommended - http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/06/09/do-not-use-context-initializers/

Instead he asked to use ITelemetryInitializers with a static value so that it is not calculated for every request.